# Data type for summing next few items

Tags: python

What data structure shall I use to represent the following table

```
'a', 1
'b', 2
'c', 3
'd', 4
'e', 5
```

so that calculating the sum of the second items in the next i rows seems natural:

e.g. when i=1

```
'a', 2
'b', 3
'c', 4
'd', 5
```

when i=2

```
'a', 2+3=5
'b', 3+4=7
'c', 4+5=9
```

when i=3

```
'a', 2+3+4=9
'b', 3+4+5=12
```

when i=4

```
'a', 2+3+4+5=14
```

My two ideas:

1. Originally I represent the table as a list of sublists:

   ```
   lst = [['a', 1],
   ['b', 2],
   ['c', 3],
   ['d', 4],
   ['e', 5]]
   ```

   but I can't figure out how to do the above calculations (in a
   natural or straightforward way). `sum(lst[0:0+i][1])` doesn't work.
   The problem about my way is how to represent a sublist of i
   consecutive values from the second column in the table, for which
   `lst[0:0+i][1]` doesn't work. (Does using two brackets side by side not work?)
2. I have another idea, but I don't know how to implement it (can someone point out if it can be implemented?):

   - split the above list into two lists, each for each column.
   - do calculations on the second column list
   - combine the first list and the result on the second column list.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[['a', 3], ['b', 5], ['c', 7], ['d', 9]]` for `i=1` ?

Comment: not include the current row.

Comment: What for `i=len(lst)`?

Comment: give `None` value, or skip the row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create the following function:

```
def my_sum(l, i):
    return [
        [x[0], sum(y[1] for y in l[j: j + i])] for j, x in enumerate(l[:-i], 1)
    ]
```

Examples:

```
>>> my_sum(lst, 1)
[['a', 2], ['b', 3], ['c', 4], ['d', 5]]
>>> my_sum(lst, 2)
[['a', 5], ['b', 7], ['c', 9]]
>>> my_sum(lst, 3)
[['a', 9], ['b', 12]]
>>> my_sum(lst, 4)
[['a', 14]]
```

**EDIT**:

Implementation based on second idea using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

def my_sum(l, i):
    a, b, n = [v[0] for v in lst], np.array([v[1] for v in lst]), len(l)
    sums = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.int)
    for j in xrange(1, i + 1):
        sums[:n - j] += b[j: n]
    return zip(a[:-i], sums[:-i])
```

Comment: Nice job on solving the entire collection problem. :)

Comment: Thanks. I wonder what advantage of using list comprehension versus explicit for loop? Faster performance? Or only more concise code?

Comment: What  "cases where performance is hurt"?  Did you answer my questions but I miss that?

Comment: Is list comprehension faster than for loop in your code? (I  wonder why list comphrehension is often favored? More logical in thinking?)

Comment: It needs to be tested...but I guess yes

Comment: Thanks.  I have a second idea, which is to split the two-col list into two lists, do calculation on the second-col list, and combine the result with the first-col list. Is it doable and a good idea?

Comment: @Tim: That's what `enumerate` (splitting) and `sum` (calculation) are doing. The same are methods in my anwer along with *more descriptive* one. @JuniorCompressor congrats for more compact code.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a 'data structure' per se, but you could try something like this:

```
labels = ['a','b','c','d','e']
vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def foo(i):
    for j in range(len(vals)-i):
        print labels[j], sum(vals[j+1:j+1+i])
```

You could also roll the whole thing into a class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary. They have keys and values to store values to variables. You can put functions, and other variables as keys.

```
mydata = {'a': 1, 'b': 2 # and so on...
         }

>>> mydata['a']
1
```

For the calculations, I'm not entirely sure how to do that... You could use `mydata.itervalues()` and get all the values and then reassign things to the keys, if you know how to handle the numbers (I'm not entirely sure about what's happening with the numbers).

Edit:

Since dictionaries aren't sorted, you could use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). As it remembers when keys are inserted, this may be a good application for its use. If you can't use it, the built-in [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function may be useful as well.

Comment: I don't think a dictionary would work, because they are unordered.

Comment: Good point... Perhaps you could you `sorted` when handling? An idea, can't remember if you can use it with dictionaries.

Comment: One other option is `collections.OrderedDict`. It's a built-in module. I haven't used it before, but it looks like this is a good application for its use.

Answer (score 1):

A bit less terse,

```
import operator
letter = operator.itemgetter(0)
number = operator.itemgetter(1)
lst = [['a', 1],   ['b', 2], ['c', 3],  ['d', 4],  ['e', 5]]
x = 3
for i, thing in enumerate(lst, 1):
    n = sum(number(other) for other in lst[i:i+3])
    print letter(thing), n 

a 9
b 12
c 9
d 5
e 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using already a structure - a list. List comprehesions are the answer:

```
def sum_next_few(lst, i):
    return [[x[0], sum(map(lambda y: y[1], lst[lst.index(x)+1:lst.index(x)+i+1]))] for x in lst[:-i]]
```

Formatted code:

```
def sum_next_few(lst, i):
    return [[
            x[0],
            sum(
                map(lambda y: y[1], lst[lst.index(x)+1:lst.index(x)+i+1])
            )] for x in lst[:-i]]
```

Or more descriptive version:

```
def sum_next_few(lst, i):
    result = []
    # We will add numbers to positions that are having successors
    for x in lst[:-i]:
        idx = lst.index(x)
        # Our string
        st = x[0]
        # Our sum
        sm = sum(map(lambda y: y[1], lst[idx+1:idx+i+1]))
        result.append([st, sm])
    return result
```

Above solution with input from your question:

```
lst = [['a', 1],
['b', 2],
['c', 3],
['d', 4],
['e', 5]]

>>> sum_next_few(lst, 1)
[['a', 2], ['b', 3], ['c', 4], ['d', 5]]
>>> sum_next_few(lst, 2)
[['a', 5], ['b', 7], ['c', 9]]
>>> sum_next_few(lst, 3)
[['a', 9], ['b', 12]]
>>> sum_next_few(lst, 4)
[['a', 14]]
>>> sum_next_few(lst, 5)
[]
```

GL, HF :)